# Setup public mirror (?) of internet server on my router

Tags: networking, router, proxy, routing

Can I somehow setup a *mirror* (this is the best word I came with) of a server available in the Internet on a specific port on my router?

Here is what I have:

- ISP provides me with a static IP adress (I was able to configure port forwarding on my router to allow access to web server in my local network from the Internet).
- I have D-LINK DIR-628 router with original firmware if that helps.
- There is an internet server which I want to mirror. More specifically this is a Ventrilo server which I rent.

What I want to achieve: 
Connecting to my router using its public IP adress should redirect the connection to Ventrilo server. I don't need any additional secure layer like any kind of authorization to use this proxy.

Reason why I need this: One guy can't connect to Ventrilo server (everyone else have no problem connecting). I don't know the exact cause of this, but his ISP is not cooperative and doesn't help him. So I want to setup some sort of mirror/proxy on my router so that he will connect using my router IP and this connection will be redirect to Ventrilo server.

I tried to setup port forwarding, but it is doesn't allow my to redirect connections to external IPs. Only to IPs on my LAN.

---

Based on information provided by @fdmillion I was able to solve my problem.

General answer (in case you need to forward only TCP):

1. I created port forwarding rule in my router as was suggested.
2. I added route to Windows using netsh command: `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=PORT listenaddress=LAN_IP_of_Windows_Machine connectport=PORT connectaddress=Internet_IP_of_Server`

However it appeared that Ventrilo is using both TCP and UDP. Unfortunately, netsh doesn't support UDP, only TCP is supported. I used separate tool to forward UDP (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/) and netsh to forward TCP. Pjs-passport can't forward TCP and UDP simultaneously. You can create only one rule for the same address and port either for TCP or for UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this sort of thing with just a consumer-grade router alone.

If you were willing to install a Linux machine somewhere inside your network and forward a port to it, you could cause Linux to use NAT to redirect the connection. While NAT is typically used to allow multiple machines inside a network to share one public IP address, NAT is not restricted to this use and can be used for all sorts of interesting routing tricks.

You could also, if your router supports it, install alternative firmware (e.g. OpenWRT) on your router and do this in the router. Even in that instance, however, some Linux background is all but required.

Obviously if you're not very familiar with Linux, this would be quite a significant learning curve just for this setup. I am not aware of apps on Windows that might be able to do this unless you're using Windows Server; Mac OS X might be able to do it using its built in firewall but I am again not sure.

For reference of anyone else looking at this, the way you might implement this would be as follows:

```
Public IP: 12.34.56.78
IP of destination server: 87.65.43.21
Local area NAT range: 192.168.1.0/24
IP of Linux box on LAN: 192.168.1.200
Port that should be forwarded: 1234

1. Use router controls to direct port 1234 of incoming traffic to 192.168.1.200.

2. On the Linux box, issue this command:

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 87.65.43.21:1234

Side note: If you are using OpenWRT or similar on a router, you would not need to forward the port as in step 1. Step 2's command would become:
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 12.34.56.78 --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 87.65.43.21:1234

3. Ensure port forwarding is on:

    sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Note that you can of course fiddle with things. If you wanted to *accept* connections on say port 4321, but still connect to port 1234, you would change the `--dport` option to match the port you want your clients to connect to. Likewise, to change the destination port, you'd modify the `--to` parameter accordingly.

If you mess things up with your firewall rules, `iptables -t nat -F` will reset all the NAT-related rules to their (empty) defaults.

`iptables` is a huge subject and a library of books could be written about it. If you do have Linux background and are interested, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/iptables and http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html are some good resources.

There are other ways to possibly accomplish the same thing - more classical proxying methods come to mind. You could, for example, setup a SOCKS5 proxy inside your network. Of course, in this instance, you must be *very diligent* with security as open SOCKS5 proxy server abuse is very common (people use open SOCKS servers to defeat IP-based bans, just to name one nasty trick.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't install OpenWRT firmware on my router because it doesn't support it. A don't have any linux machine on my LAN as well. The only two machines I have both run Windows 7. I'm trying to figure out what would be an analog for iptables on Windows. Looks like netsh is what I need, but I didn't figure out how to create such a route using it yet.

Comment: I was able to work out a solution based on your comment. I edited my original question with a solution which I came to in case anyone have similar question. Thanks once again!